# Toggling line numbers in vimrc doesn't work

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm new to vim.
I'm using MacVim.

I use

```
:set number
```

which shows line numbers.

I've added

```
set number
```

to my vimrc, to make show line numbers by default.

My vimrc:

```
no <down> <Nop>
no <left> <Nop>
no <right> <Nop>
no <up> <Nop>
ino <down> <Nop>
ino <left> <Nop>
ino <right> <Nop>
ino <up> <Nop>
set number
```

But line numbers don't show up.

Everything in vimrc except `set number` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are those lines all you have in the vimrc?

Comment: Did you restart `vim` or reload `.vimrc` after adding this line?

Comment: Yes thats all that i have in vim rc.
Yes I reloaded and restarted few times.

Comment: where did you put your `.vimrc` file? the path, I mean

Comment: in the '~/.vim/.vimrc'

Comment: Do you have a `.gvimrc` file?  The contents of such a file would get loaded after your `.vimrc`, and would override those settings.  Other files to check are anything inside `~/.vim/after/`, if that directory exists.

Comment: @TrevorPowell There waas no `.gvimrc` in my `~/.vim`. 
`ls ~/.vim` showed: `. .. .vimrc`.
I created empty `.gvimrc` using vim, restarted it. And now 
**it throws sound alerts on any keydown and it doesn't respond to keyboard at all.**
 hahaha i love this kind of stuff when you are fixing minor issue and in the process break everything))))
Could you point me to an article or something about `.vimrc`VS`.gvimrc`? Or maybe you can explain how they work and stuff. I understand that `.gvimrc` should contain stuff related to graphics, and `.vimrc` everything else, is this correct?

Comment: @TrevorPowell I deleted and than created again `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc`. Now there is no problem with keyboard, but set number lines still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd comment but I'm not allowed :(

I usually have had that problem when either the file or the line is corrupted or has Ctrl characters or in someversions of Unix if there was a space in the wrong place

try  :set list and make sure there isn't a Tab, missing Line Feed or something

There's a way of viewing the Control Characters that don't display in :set list but can't remember it.

Shove comes to push delete the line and the one above and below. Save and retype it andsee if it fixes it.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested, sadly no effect.
set list shows only '$' after the lines. Nothing suspicious. I fiddled with stuff like deleting file, re typing, pasting, changing the order of elements, and so on. Nothing changes. Those 8 top(no matter of there order) lines have effect, 'set number' doesn't.

Comment: Weird. Try :set number? to check the status in a fresh Vim. Then try :set verbose=1 then :set number? to see if one of your plugins is playing up

Comment: Done what you asked nothing, bur interesting happened. 

 Then I've done 'set verbose=15' because from the docs it looks like a proper way to debug '.vimrc', but it gives a lot of information.
I've noticed the line '"~/.vim/.vimrc" 9L, 141C' wivh as I understand tells us that it read '.vimrc' from the right location and the number of lines is correct so it for sure read the whole file. 

I've got no pluggins in vim. It's a fresh copy from which I installed through homebrew few days ago.

I suspect that all this problem has something to do with over reading my '.vimrc' with default one.

Answer (score 3):

Problem was that I had one `.vimrc` in the `~/` and one in the `~/.vim/.vimrc`. 
The one that was in the `~/` was overriding the one in in `~/.vim/.vimrc`.